# EF Core Fix issues After SaveChanges Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have this piece of code (in Asp.net core), I try to add a list of objects to DB:

```
try
   {
      await _context.AddRangeAsync(mhUserAtts);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
catch()
   {

   }
```

When some objects conflict with DB, how can I remove them from the list?
And then return to save the rest to DB.

Comment: If you want complete database write, you should add your entity and save changes for each object

Comment: I preferred to use the `AddRangeAsync` as a single line and benefits of its performance

Comment: If you use ```AddRange``` the whole insert process will be rolled back if any of your entity failed on writing and committing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to suggested answer in comment, If you want the single query to be executed for entry, you can filter already existing records and attempt to add those which are new as following.

```
try
   {
      var userAttsInDb =  await _context.UserAtt.Where(u => mhUserAtts.Any(x => x.Id == 
         u.Id)).Select(u => u.Id).ToArrayAsync();
      var mhUserAttsToAdd= mhUserAtts.Where(u => !userAttsInDb.Contains(u.Id));

      await _context.AddRangeAsync(mhUserAttsToAdd);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
catch(){ }
```

Note: you may need to handle async await properly.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good approach, I wonder if there are error assigned for each object state returned when _context failure to save them in db. Like in earlier ADO.net

Comment: If the database is accessed from multiple threads or processes, the data may have been changed between two database queries. Which can lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use transactions (if you db supports it)

```
public async Task MyDataProcessingAsync(CancellationToken token) {
        using var context = new DbContext();
        using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(token);
        try {
            // adding, removing, updating...
            await context.SaveChangesAsync(token);
            await transaction.CommitAsync(token);
        }
        catch {
            // undo all changes
            await transaction.RollbackAsync();
            throw;
        }
    }
```